# Is there an equivalent of create-react-app for Node apps?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, react-scripts

I often use create-react-app for creating React apps. One of the nice things about it is that it preconfigures your project with useful tools such as Babel, react-scripts, etc.

Is there something equivalent for Node apps? It'd be nice if there was some way to quickly create a Node app that's already preconfigured to work with Babel and such.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t care about opinionated frameworks, you have options like nest.js or feathers.js that can give you a nice start for your projects.
If you only need a simple express app you can use `express-generator` to configure a server in seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should look at this: https://nextjs.org/ for a complete solution (backend and frontend in node). And you can also build a static web app with this.

And also https://vitejs.dev/ as a lightweight alternative to CRA.